# Proper way to check system requirements for a WordPress plugin

Tags: error-handling, conditional-statements, wordpress, system-requirements

I am curious about the proper way to stop a user from activating my plugin if their system does not meet certain requirements. Doing the checks is easy and I don't need any help with that, I am more curious how to tell WordPress to exit and display an error message.

Currently I have tried both `exit($error_message)` and `die($error_message)` in the activation hook method. While my message is displayed and the plugin is not activated, a message saying Fatal Error is also displayed (see image below).

[image]

Does anyone know of a better way, that would display my message in a proper error box without displaying Fatal error, it just looks really bad for new users to see that.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little undocumented, as you might have noticed. Instead of `die()`, do it like this:

```
$plugin = dirname(__FILE__) . '/functions.php';
deactivate_plugins($plugin);
wp_die('<p>The <strong>X</strong> plugin requires version WordPress 2.8 or greater.</p>','Plugin Activation Error',array('response'=>200,'back_link'=>TRUE));
```

The lines above wp_die() are to deactivate this plugin. Note that we use functions.php in this case because that's where I have my Plugin Name meta data comment declaration -- and if you use a different file, then change the code above. Note that the path is very specific for a match. So, if you want to see what your path would normally be, use `print_r(get_option('active_plugins'));die();` to dump that out so that you know what path you need. Since I had a plugin_code.php where the rest of my plugin code was, and since it was in the same directory as functions.php, I merely had to do `dirname(__FILE__)` for the proper path.

Note that the end of the wp_die() statement is important because it provides a backlink and prevents an error 500 (which is the default Apache code for wp_die()).

Comment: just got back on stack overflow, so sorry for the late response to your answer. I'll check it out later this week and mark it as the answer after verified. Thanks again for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

It is only a idea though. Try checking the wordpress version and compare then use php to through custom exception/error. PHP 5.0 try catch can be a good way to do it. Here is some resources.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.throw.php

You can try the first link. It is pretty basic. Thanks! hope the information will be helpful.

Comment: Good call, I will have to look into that. Do you know if WordPress has a built in activation exception handler or something similar that may catch an exception?

Comment: I am not sure if wordpress have this kinds of handlers. But as it is very easy in php wordpress most likely won't have.